# Got "token": [ "Ensure this field has no more than 500 characters." ] in drf social oauth2

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'drf_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    ),
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    # drf-social-oauth2
    'drf_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',
    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = 'my key'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'my secrect'

# Define SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE to get extra permissions from Facebook.
# Email is not sent by default, to get it, you must request the email permission.
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
]
```

I am using drf-social-oauth2 for Google login. After getting a Google credential from React site. i tried to use 'curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<django-oauth-generated-client_id>&client_secret=<django-oauth-generated-client_secret>&backend=google-oauth2&token=<google_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token'
But I got "token": ["Ensure this field has no more than 500 characters."]

Answer (score 1):

You can try with version 1.3.0 or 2.0.0

I'm using microsoft graph as backend and encountered same issue too in version > 2.0.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).